# How to cause args to enter an endless loop?

Tags: c#

I have a console application that uses a number of command line switches to control various methods. Each of the command line switches is handled by a switch statement that is within a for loop that iterates over each of the args.

```
        for (int x = 0; x < args.Length; x++)
        {
            switch (args[x])
            {
             ...
            }
         }
```

This works perfectly for my needs, however I need to add a --loop switch that causes the preceding args to be looped indefinitely based upon a timeout period specified by the --set-timeout switch.

The code I have so far is:

```
switch (args[x])
{
   case "--set-timeout-5m":
       timeout = 300000;
       System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(timeout);
       break;

       ....

    case "--loop":
        x = 0;
        break;
 }
```

The problem is setting x does not cause the for loop to continue from the start of args. It just sits there.

I am expecting x to have scope as the code is within the for loop and no errors are generated in Visual Studio. I am also expecting the break statement to break the case and pass x to the for loop.

Can anyone explain why it does not work or perhaps post a workaround?

Comment: Your "set timeout" is not setting a timeout, it is causing the loop to immediately sleep for 5 minutes.  Is that what you mean to do?

Comment: It is, the set timeout is to cause the code to pause for n amount of minutes, the --loop switch is what should control the looping. The use case would be like program.exe -i --set-timeout-5m --loop

Comment: What do you mean just sits there? Try debugging and see where your code goes to at the break.

Comment: So with the arguments in your comment you want it to loop for 5 minutes, then stop?  Currently it'll wait for 5 minutes, then loop indefinitely.

Comment: It should work. Are you sure your "--loop" case is being hit? Try putting a breakpoint on the "x = 0;".

Comment: It should loop indefinitely, however it is not. I am running a debug test to see what happens with it currently. Once I have more data I will post, unless someone gives me that "A HA!" moment :D

Comment: Well there was a post that mentioned setting x to -1 as it was being set to 1 at each iteration due to the x++ (of course!), setting x to -1 may have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    Console.Write(x);
    x = 0;
}
```

prints

```
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

because `x++` is executed after each iteration.

If you want it to print

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

you need to change it to

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    Console.Write(x);
    x = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Thread.Sleep` will just block the current thread. To set a timeout, get the current date before the loop:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
```

Then, on each iteration, check if the current time has exceeded the timeout, and if it has, break out of the loop:

```
if(DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds >= timeout) {
    // Stop your processin'!
}
```